# Python: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\**********\\MP7'

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I am trying to compile my code on window cmd. While I run my py file, the error is: C:\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't find '**main**' module in 'C:\Users\tdd24\ECE 615 Vivado\MP7'. I have run part of the code in jupyter notebook, and it does not have this error. I cannot find the problem. Any help?

```
import serial
import struct


file1 = open(r'C:\Users\tdd24\ECE 615 Vivado\signal.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = 'COM4', # /dev/ttyUSB0 in Linux
    baudrate=115200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
    )
# Strips the newline character
for line in Lines:
    newpack = struct.pack('f', line)
    ser.write(newpack)
#############################    

file1.close()

ser.isOpen()
readbyte = 0
readstring = ""
print("Waiting for input")
while (readbyte != '\n'):
    readbyte = ser.read(1).decode("utf-8")
    readstring = readstring + readbyte
    
print(readstring)
ser.close()
```

The command I used on cmd

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.867]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\tdd24>python --version
Python 3.8.5

C:\Users\tdd24>python "C:\Users\tdd24\ECE 615 Vivado\MP7"
C:\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Users\\tdd24\\ECE 615 Vivado\\MP7'

C:\Users\tdd24>
```

Comment: Are you saving this file as a `.py`?

Comment: Please include the *full* error message. Also, make sure your code here is actually a [mcve] and doesn't include things that aren't needed to demonstrate the problem. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I have include the full error message. @ObjectJosh it is a .py file, I failed to compile it on cmd because it cannot find the main module

Comment: `.py` files are not compiled. Can you show how exactly are you trying to run this and what is the exact error?

Comment: I do not think I can take screen shoot. So the python I need to do is read a .txt file, convert all of them to serial data and send to a FPGA device through serial port. I run it by command      C:\Users\tdd24>python "C:\Users\tdd24\ECE 615 Vivado\MP7" . And it show the error I mentioned above

Answer (score -1):

On windows, you need to have the following within the executed .py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

You could either wrap all of your code into a function and call it from **main**, or you could nest it within main. Former is probably the better option as it is starting you down the road toward segmenting your code.

i.e.

```
def Function1():
    file1 = open(r'C:\Users\tdd24\ECE 615 Vivado\signal.txt', 'r')
    Lines = file1.readlines()

    #This is your call below, I'm not sure it'll work with comments in the middle, but leaving unchanged to focus on the main point of your query.
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port = 'COM4', # /dev/ttyUSB0 in Linux
        baudrate=115200,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
    )

    # Strips the newline character
    for line in Lines:
        newpack = struct.pack('f', line)
        ser.write(newpack)
    #############################    

    file1.close()

    ser.isOpen()
    readbyte = 0
    readstring = ""
    print("Waiting for input")
    while (readbyte != '\n'):
        readbyte = ser.read(1).decode("utf-8")
    readstring = readstring + readbyte

    print(readstring)
    ser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Starting point for windows execution
    Function1()
```

Comment: *"you __need__ to have"* is quite strong. There is no ***need*** for that guard. It is not mandatory

Comment: What's the alternative for calling a .py via cmd?

Unless you are passing declarations in?

Comment: What do you mean? You just run it from cmd line Keeping in mind that everything is ran. This guard is meant for other files importing your file

Comment: Oh - I didn't realise we could get away with just having a main()... not that such a thing is advisable. edit: We don't even need that much either!! That's a little bit out of control for me! I'll stick to main for structure!!!